# Jekyll Kramdown Footnotes Not Parsing

Tags: jekyll, footnotes, kramdown, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm attempting to annotate a file with footnotes using Jekyll.  My _config.yml file is set thusly:

markdown: kramdown

This is how I'm attempting to use the footnotes:

```
<p>As trade-off talking rational economic people [^1], we are constantly making choices that have different costs associated with them.</p>
[^1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade-off_talking_rational_economic_person`
```

But viewing it in my local machine it doesn't seem to parse the first footnote.  This is how it shows up:

"As trade-off talking rational economic people [^1], we are constantly making choices that have different costs associated with them."

The footnote definition does not appear.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell kramdown to parse inside html, This can be done in your code, like this :

```
<p markdown="1">As trade-off talking rational economic people [^1], we are constantly making choices that have different costs associated with them.</p>
```

Or, you can configure kramdown in your `_config.yml`

```
# be sure that you use kramdown as markdown processor
markdown: kramdown

# configure kramdown
kramdown:
  parse_block_html: true
```

[See kramdown documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks)

Comment: I tried confirguring kramdown, which didn't seem to do anything.  However, telling it to parse within the paragraph tags worked perfectly.

Comment: I have the same problem and like David, configuring kramdown didn't work for me neither. But I didn't understand the first solution, I also read kramdown's documentation but I couldn't understand. The code you've written is in HTML, I put it in my .md file and it didn't work; was this what I was supposed to do?