# No luck in making footnotes render in Jekyll and kramdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I try with no success to make my footnote markup work as described in [kramdown documentation](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks):

```
Lore Ipsum [^1] lore ipsum
```

and below the page

```
[^1]: my footnote here
```

Instead I don't have the markup rendered.

In Jekyll config file I have:

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

I don't want to use the solution offered here: [Jekyll Kramdown Footnotes Not Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379364/jekyll-kramdown-footnotes-not-parsing) since it forces me to add html markup in my paragraph which I prefer to avoid.

I also tried

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  parse_block_html: true
```

which exposed my liquid markup in the page messing up my layouts.

I wonder why is not working out-of-the-box in an almost vanilla setting.